# How to get most occuring element(s) in a list of strings, also when there are many with the same count?

Tags: python, list

Output is expected to be a list of string as well.

For example `['hey', 'ho', 'hi', 'hey', 'ho']` should output `['hey', 'ho']`

```
def find_most_popular(list):
    popular = max(set(list), key=list.count)
    return popular
```

My code only outputs the one most popular

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need (i used "l" instead of "list" to avoid confusion with built in data type "list"):

```
def find_most_popular(l):
    popular = [i for i in l if l.count(i)==max([l.count(p) for p in set(l)])]
    return list(set(popular))
```

For

```
your_list=['hey', 'ho', 'hi', 'hey', 'ho']
```

Result will be:

```
find_most_popular(your_list)

['hey', 'ho']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(['hey', 'ho', 'hi', 'hey', 'ho'])
print([k for k, v in c.items() if v==c.most_common()[0][1]])
```

Prints:

```
['hey', 'ho']
```